# Simple joystick hid report descriptor doesn't work

Tags: usb, report, hid, joystick, usb-descriptor

Using atmega8 chip and V-USB library I made a little bridge to connect my NES gamepad to USB. At first I used one of examples as my hid descriptor and so...
I had my device correctly recognized in Windows when I set it to handshake with this 
HID report descriptor

```
PROGMEM const char usbHidReportDescriptor[100] = {
    0x05, 0x01,                    // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x15, 0x00,                    // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x09, 0x04,                    // USAGE (Joystick)
    0xa1, 0x01,                    // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x05, 0x02,                    //   USAGE_PAGE (Simulation Controls)
    0x09, 0xbb,                    //   USAGE (Throttle)
    0x15, 0x81,                    //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
    0x25, 0x7f,                    //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
    0x75, 0x08,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x95, 0x01,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0x81, 0x02,                    //   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    0x05, 0x01,                    //   USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x01,                    //   USAGE (Pointer)
    0xa1, 0x00,                    //   COLLECTION (Physical)
    0x09, 0x30,                    //     USAGE (X)
    0x09, 0x31,                    //     USAGE (Y)
    0x95, 0x02,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (2)
    0x81, 0x02,                    //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    0xc0,                          //   END_COLLECTION
    0x09, 0x39,                    //   USAGE (Hat switch)
    0x15, 0x00,                    //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x03,                    //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (3)
    0x35, 0x00,                    //   PHYSICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x46, 0x0e, 0x01,              //   PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM (270)
    0x65, 0x14,                    //   UNIT (Eng Rot:Angular Pos)
    0x75, 0x04,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (4)
    0x95, 0x01,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0x81, 0x02,                    //   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    0x05, 0x09,                    //   USAGE_PAGE (Button)
    0x19, 0x01,                    //   USAGE_MINIMUM (Button 1)
    0x29, 0x04,                    //   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 4)
    0x15, 0x00,                    //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x01,                    //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x75, 0x01,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (1)
0x95, 0x04,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (4)
0x55, 0x00,                    //   UNIT_EXPONENT (0)
0x65, 0x00,                    //   UNIT (None)
0x81, 0x02,                    //   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
0xc0                           // END_COLLECTION
};
```

and this report type

```
typedef struct{
    char    throttle;
    char    x;
    char    y;
    uchar    hatSwitchAndButtons;
}report_t;
```

But when I made it simpler:

```
PROGMEM const char usbHidReportDescriptor[48] =  {
    0x05, 0x01,                    // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x04,                    // USAGE (Joystick)
    0xa1, 0x01,                    // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x15, 0x81,                    //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
    0x25, 0x7f,                    //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
    0x05, 0x01,                    //   USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x01,                    //   USAGE (Pointer)
    0xa1, 0x00,                    //   COLLECTION (Physical)
    0x09, 0x30,                    //     USAGE (X)
    0x09, 0x31,                    //     USAGE (Y)
    0x75, 0x08,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x95, 0x02,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (2)
    0x81, 0x02,                    //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    0xc0,                          //   END_COLLECTION
    0x05, 0x09,                    //   USAGE_PAGE (Button)
    0x19, 0x01,                    //   USAGE_MINIMUM (Button 1)
    0x29, 0x04,                    //   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 8)
    0x15, 0x00,                    //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x01,                    //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x75, 0x01,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (1)
    0x95, 0x04,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (8)
    0x55, 0x00,                    //   UNIT_EXPONENT (0)
    0x65, 0x00,                    //   UNIT (None)
    0x81, 0x02,                    //   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    0xc0                           // END_COLLECTION
};

typedef struct{
    char    x;
    char    y;
    uchar    buttons;
}report_t;
```

Windows has not been unable to install my joystick. It will still recognize it's name but will fail to finish installation.

I'm confused because USB Hid Tool validates this report descriptor.

Any idea, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
0x29, 0x04,                    //   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 8)
0x95, 0x04,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (8)
```

Ooops, looks like someone programms with comments. :)
Change 0x04 to 0x08. And watch so that each report size could be devided by 8 (8,16,24,32 etc.)